# "What bad if" or "what's bad if" in rhetirical questions?

Tags: grammar

Could you tell which one of the following sentences is coreect?

> **What bad** if I don't have a degree! I can always obtain it.
>
> **What's bad** if I don't have a degree! I can always obtain it.

What I'm trying to say is that there is nothing wrong with the fact that I don't have a degree.

Comment: If you want to use the word ***bad*** in such context, it needs to be slightly "qualified". Your examples aren't acceptable to native speakers, but *What's **so** bad **about me not having** a degree! I can always obtain it* is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these is particularly idiomatic. I would say:

> What does it matter if I don't have a degree?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context. Will you say this in a formal circumstance, or to a friend?

In an informal environment you could say

> So what if I don't have a degree? I can always obtain/get one.

or

> I don't have a degree, so what? I can always get one.

In a more formal situation you could say:

> I personally believe that the fact that I do not possess a degree presents no problem. I can always obtain one.